# socket programming beginner

Tags: sockets, networking

Lets say I have a tablet PC running a GUI application, and a remote PC (with static IP) running the backend core stuff.

The application running on the PC should request information from the Server.

Now I was thinking of socket programming, where the server will be running a server socket application and the tablet PC a client socket application.

But is there a simpler thing? I know ftp protocol is used to transfer files, is there a high level protocol like ftp that can be used to transfer small binary data, 16 bits per request? so I don't have to do any socket programming?

If the answer is only using socket programming, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you really want is an [Application Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server). If you choose to use sockets, you will have to deal with a lot of low-level details, such as marshalling / unmarshalling. You can opt for a higher-level solution:

- [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba);
- [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)-based web server, perhaps using [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) for transferring requests / replies;
- add your favourite RPC / RMI framework here.

Comment: These might be a bit overkill if Kam really only needs to transfer 16 bits per request.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, you are absolutely right, but to be honest I wanted to transfer 16bits per request and then define the protocol on both ends so that my server can make sence of the received data. But when I read about CORBA I realized that I don't need to define anything, I can just do function calls from the client and the server will do the processing :D

Answer (score 1):

Socket programming is indeed what you want here.  Check out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) to get yourself started.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, you are absolutely right, but to be honest I wanted to transfer 16bits per request and then define the protocol on both ends so that my server can make sence of the received data. But when I read about CORBA I realized that I don't need to define anything, I can just do function calls from the client and the server will do the processing :D

Comment: BTW, Beej's Guide to Network Programming is awesome, I've been reading it since you first mentioned it.